# How do we mount multiple disks into a single storagepool in OpenEBS?

Tags: kubernetes, storage, openebs

How do we mount multiple disks into a single storagepool?
Currently, the doc talks about mounting only a single path.

Comment: @Chandan_Sagar_Pradhan You should specify the doc link or whatever you wish.

Comment: @Chandan: I think that your question is for SuperUser site, not for this one. StackOverflow is for CODE. I propose that your remove your question from this site and post the same question on SuperUser that is a Q&A site from StackExchange galaxy.